# MOTO G4 is not connecting with windows 10

Tags: usb-connection-mode, data-transfer, 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g-4g

I am using moto g4 plus, Im trying to connect my moto with ma laptop through. My phone got latest android 7.0 update but now also same issue is there. Please suggest some way.

**USB** but its not getting connected.This allow me to charge through the usb. But im tried the most of the method to connect .Please anybody can help me ..

I am also an android developer so my phone allow me to connect with android studio and deploy the app in my phone but it not allowing me to explore the folders on sd card or phone memory through explorer.

Comment: "tried the most of the method to connect" What exactly have you tried? There's no point people suggesting things you've already tried, so please [edit] your question so people don't waste their time this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. First turn on developer options. To do this open settings and locate the 'about phone' and tap this then scroll to build and tap this 7 times then click the back button and go back to settings. With your phone connected to the computer locate 'Developer options' and tap it. From here scroll down to 'Select USB Configuration' and tap it. Tap 'MTP(Media Transfer Protocol)' even though it may already be selected. This should automatically open the dialog box on the computer with the phone's drive listed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have drivers installed? Check for MTP USB drivers.
Also you may need to have a look [here](http://support.bell.ca/Mobility/Smartphones_and_mobile_internet/Motorola-Moto-G.how_to_change_the_usb_connection_options_on_my)

As your phone only shows photo, it's because the USB settings is set to PTP.

To see phone content on PC, pull down notification bar on phone when phone is connected and switch from PTP to MTP mode.

Comment: Thanks i have tried this also but it is not getting connected

Comment: what happens when you plug the USB cable? what operating system is your PC running? If Windows, open the device manager and see if there are devices that need drivers

Comment: or you may check your USB cable if it is damaged or check the USB charging port for dust or something

Comment: while im trying to connect ma phone with ma PC it allow me to charge and share only photos. But i really want that the full file manager IE the all the list of folders and the files in my phone and SD card. But now it shows only the camera folders in both SD card and the internal memory.

Comment: i have checked ma USB cable it is working fine. Please help me.

Comment: oh I get now. Your USB connection is set to PTP, you should change it to MTP

Comment: I have checked that too.. But it is not showing anything on my screen.. that means it is not able to connect with pc . Thanks for your advice .

Comment: did you pull down the notification bar? I really believe it drivers problem

Comment: I'm also think so.But my other phones are connecting but i'm facing the issue for only motto G4. Can you please guide where i get drivers for the same.

Comment: try this : http://www.teamandroid.com/download-android-usb-drivers/

Comment: i tried this too but not working .

Answer (score 0):

My MotoG4 loses its USB Brains all the time.

Developer Options>Select USB Configuration.

Even though its already set top MTP (media Transfer Protocol) it really isnt. Toggle the USB Configuration to PTP and back to MTP a couple of times that usually fixes it.